# Not able to post content starting with '@' using Guzzle

Tags: php, twitter, guzzle

I use Guzzle to post data on Twitter, once I try to reply to any tweet and set original tweet user handler in reply content. Then final content looks like as

```
$input = array('status' => '@abhishekm2040 Hi with screenname again.', 
           'in_reply_to_status_id' => '2345454545');
```

Then I am getting error message for status contents

```
 "message": "Unable to open abhishekm2040 Hi with screenname again. for reading",
```

because of the following code:

__src/thirdparty/Guzzle/Http/Message/RequestFactory.php

```
if (is_array($body) || $body instanceof Collection) {
                // Normalize PHP style cURL uploads with a leading '@' symbol
                foreach ($body as $key => $value) {
                    if (is_string($value) && substr($value, 0, 1) == '@') {
                        $request->addPostFile($key, $value);
                        unset($body[$key]);
                    }
                }
                // Add the fields if they are still present and not all files
                $request->addPostFields($body);
            }
```

kindly let me know how can I fix this issue.

https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle3/issues/57

Comment: It seems that this library treat a body message with `@` at the beginning as attending a file upload (`$addPostFile`). Why not using a twitter API dedicated library?

Comment: I took Twitter just as example.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by understanding the **why**.

Guzzle use cURL, therefore I took a look at the php cURL manual and according to it, here's the definition of the [**`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) option (which is "responsible" for the data):

> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file,
>   prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. The filetype can be
>   explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the
>   format ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can either be passed as a
>   urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with
>   the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array,
>   the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data. As of PHP
>   5.2.0, value must be an array if files are passed to this option with the @ prefix. As of PHP 5.5.0, the @ prefix is deprecated and files
>   can be sent using CURLFile. The @ prefix can be disabled for safe
>   passing of values beginning with @ by setting the CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD
>   option to TRUE.

So the behavior you've mentioned is rational and logical.
Please notice to the last 2 lines in the explanation above:

> **As of PHP 5.5.0, the @ prefix is deprecated and files
>   can be sent using CURLFile.The @ prefix can be disabled for safe passing of > values beginning with @ by setting the CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD option to TRUE.**

The solution would be to set the `CURLOP_SAFE_UPLOAD` option to `TRUE` but since you're using a framework - it would require some work. Something like:

//Your new input array

```
$input = array('status' => '@abhishekm2040 Hi with screenname again.', 
           'in_reply_to_status_id' => '2345454545',
           'ignore_a' => true);
```

And in the framework's code:

```
            if(isset($body['ignore_a']) && $body['ignore_a']){
               $ignore_a = true;
               //Here you should set the curlop_safe_upload option to true.
               //Since i'm not familiar with that framework I don't know
               //how to do it.
               //Update: It seems that the framework doesn't has a `setCurlOpt` function so you'll just have to write one.
            } else {
               $ignore_a = false;
            }

            foreach ($body as $key => $value) {
                if (!$ignore_a && is_string($value) && substr($value, 0, 1) == '@') {
                    $request->addPostFile($key, $value);
                    unset($body[$key]);
                }
            }
```

(Please notice that i havent' tested this code and it was written just in order to show the general idea)

If you consider the first part of the last 2 lines: @ prefix is deprecated as for PHP 5.5.0. It means that probably in a newer version of that framework - it won't happen for you.

I added a link to this answer on your GitHub thread. Please notice that as that framework already has a newer version, it developers might not work on it and will just offer you to get the newer version.

Comment: Has it helped you to figure a way to solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for solution, but modification in thirdparty library not a good idea. Trying to update the Guzzle thirdparty library...

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved once I updated latest Guzzle library.

Thanks Ofir Baruch for direction